# Questions regarding Gauge and Darboux Integrals?

Tags: integration, summation, riemann-sum, gauge-integral

Can the Gauge Integral exist on a function defined on a countable set? What would it equal?

I was wondering because if we took the Darboux Integral of $f:C\cap[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ where $C$ is a countable dense set and $f$ is continuous in $C$, the integral is the same as the Darboux Integral of $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$.

The definition of all known integrals state $f$ has to be defined in $[a,b]$ ? Why so? What are they trying to avoid?

Comment: Darboux integral (if it exists) equals Lebesgue integral, assuming measure is usual measure on real line.  In that case Lebesgue integral over a countable set is zero.

Comment: @herbsteinberg What if we took the Darboux sum of  $x$ for $x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ without the “$f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ criteria”?  If we divided $[0,1]$ into 10 partitions what is the supremum of $[0,1/10]$? Isn’t it $1/10$. What is the Infimum? Isn’t it zero. If we apply this to the other $9$ partitions we get the same supremums and infimums as $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ for $g(x)=x$. As the partitions get smaller we get the same results as the Darboux Integral of $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$.......

Comment: @herbsteinberg ..........However the Lebesgue Integral and (presumably the Gauge Integral) say the integral of $s:[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ for $s(x)=x$ is zero.

Comment: We seem to be in agreement?  The integral = $0$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Check the comment where I talk about the Darboux sum. The Lebesgue Integral does not equal the limit of the Darboux sum and hence the Darboux Integral. If we ignore the criteria $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and replace it with $f:C\cap[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ where $C$ is a countable set dense in $[a,b]$, $f$ has the same Darboux sum limit, and integral, as $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg In the case of $x$ for $x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ the limit of the darboux sum gives $1/2$, while the Lebesgue integral gives zero.There is a conflict. Read all my comments to see why.

Comment: I am unable to follow your details, but you seem to have a lower Darbous sum of $0$.  What is $f$ outside of $C$?  Are you integrating over $[a,b]$ or over $C\cap [a,b]$?  If the latter, what is the measure you are using for the countable set?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I'm not using a measure, just darboux sum. For $f(x)=x$ and $f:\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, $\inf_{x\in[0,1/5]}x+\inf_{x\in[1/5,2/5]}x+\inf_{x\in[2/5,3/5]}x+\inf_{x\in[3/5,4/5]}x+\inf_{x\in[4/5,1]}x=0 \times 1/5+1/5 \times 1/5+2/5 \times 1/5+3/5 \times 1/5+4/5 \times 1/5=10/25=2/5$ and $\sup_{x\in[0,1/5]}x+\sup_{x\in[1/5,2/5]}x+\sup_{x\in[2/5,3/5]}x+\inf_{x\in[3/5,4/5]}x+\inf_{x\in[4/5,1]}x=1/5 \times 1/5+2/5 \times 1/5+3/5 \times 1/5+4/5 \times 1/5+1 \times 1/5=3/5$. Remember focus on defined points and discard undefined. Note that $\frac{2}{5}<\frac{1}{2}<\frac{3}{5}$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg If you saw the calculations, the darboux sum of $f:\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is the same as the sum of $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I got what you are doing.  To say the least, what you are doing is unusual.  I am puzzled as to why.  As for your last question - I guess it has to with the fact that integral in its simplest form is used to get an area under a curve, so the domain is an interval.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I keep posting because I'm afraid I will never graduate from college. In case that happens, I need someone to look into this. I want to publish a paper in a magazine or undergraduate journal on these functions, their graph, derivatives, intuition behind the integrals, and various measures to apply. I have other [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295312/how-to-rigorously-define-an-integral-that-does-the-following?noredirect=1#comment6797660_3295312) hidden in this website.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Sambo’s answer gives a good reason. Additivity of the domains would not work. However, the Integral gives an appropriate average of $f$. My argument is the additivity of the domains is only needed when $f[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$; otherwise the relationship between the integral and the average is more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that in your context, $f$ is a function defined (and continuous, for simplicity) on all of $[a,b]$. If this is not a fair assumption let me know and I will edit (or delete) my answer.

Let $C$ be a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. As you noted, applying the definition of the Darboux integral (in particular with Darboux sums) to $f$ while only considering the domain $C \cap [a,b]$ yields the same result as the Darboux integral of $f$. For lack of better notation, I will denote the limiting Darboux sum of $f$ when restricted to $C \cap [a,b]$ by:

\begin{align*}
\int_{C \cap [a,b]} \left. f \right|_{C \cap [a,b]}
\end{align*}

So, what you have noticed is that:

\begin{align*}
\int_{C \cap [a,b]} \left. f \right|_{C \cap [a,b]} = \int_{[a,b]} f
\end{align*}

(I have not checked that this is always true, but I suspect that it is if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.)

The reason, then, that we don't use this as a definition for the integral of $f$ over $C \cap [a,b]$ is that **we lose a nice property of integration**: additivity of the domain.

Let $g_1 : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g_2 : [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that $[a,b] \cap [c,d] = \varnothing$. Define $g : [a,b] \cup [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
g(x) = \left\{
\begin{matrix}
g_1(x) & \text{if } x \in [a,b] \\
g_2(x) & \text{if } x \in [c,d]
\end{matrix}
\right.
\end{align*}
Then we have the following nice property:

\begin{align*}
\int_{[a,b]\cup[c,d]} g = \int_{[a,b]} g_1 + \int_{[c,d]} g_2
= \int_{[a,b]} \left. g \right|_{[a,b]} + \int_{[c,d]} \left. g \right|_{[c,d]}
\end{align*}

As it turns out, with your definition, this no longer holds. Consider the following example. Let $C_1 = \mathbb{Q}$, and let $C_2 = \mathbb{Q} + \sqrt{2} = \{ q + \sqrt{2} : q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Then both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are countable dense sets, and their intersection is $\varnothing$. Therefore their union, $C = C_1 \cup C_2$, is also countable and dense.

But then by your definition, we should have:

\begin{align*}
\int_{C_1 \cap [a,b]} \left. f \right|_{C_1 \cap [a,b]} 
= \int_{C_2 \cap [a,b]} \left. f \right|_{C_2 \cap [a,b]}
= \int_{C \cap [a,b]} \left. f \right|_{C \cap [a,b]}
= \int_{[a,b]} f
\end{align*}

And so, as long as $\int_{[a,b]} f \neq 0$, we end up with:

\begin{align*}
\int_{C_1 \cap [a,b]} \left. f \right|_{C_1 \cap [a,b]} 
+ \int_{C_2 \cap [a,b]} \left. f \right|_{C_2 \cap [a,b]}
\neq \int_{C \cap [a,b]} \left. f \right|_{C \cap [a,b]}
\end{align*}

Since additivity of the domain is one of the most important features of the integral, we choose not to use the definition you proposed. Instead, we agree that the integral over a countable dense set is either undefined (as per the Darboux integral) or zero (as per the Lebesgue integral).

Comment: Good point, but what is the average? If we took the average in terms of the Lebesgue Integral, it is zero. But intuitively the domain could be greater.

Comment: It seems the average in terms of the integral wouldn’t work in this case. We could just extend the countable set to all real numbers. But then again what is the average if $f(x)$ in $[0,1]$ is $2$ at $x\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Q}^2$ and $1$ at $x\in\mathbb{Q}^2$? We can’t use the Lebesgue Integral, intuitively if the average exists, it has to be greater than zero. The Darboux Integral says it does not exist but does not give an average for the Derichlet function. We need something different.

Comment: @Arbuja Are you trying to integrate or take an average? These are not the same thing.

Comment: Shouldn’t the average use integration? It many not be the same thing but there is a relationship.

Comment: Ok...they are not the same thing. But wouldn’t it be easier to compute the average if we used an integral? The average of $f$ is the same as $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f=F$ at $x=C$. In my opinion, integration with additivity works if the measure of the domain is $1$ but not otherwise. Otherwise, it is best to use an Integral that gives an appropriate average.

Comment: What is your goal here? To define the average of a function defined on a countable dense set?

Comment: The Integral is the “area under the curve”. The countable set has points so infinitesimally close to each other we can ignore the undefind singularities. So taking the integral of $f$ is like taking the integral on the extension of its domain to all real numbers.

Comment: If you have $f$ defined only on $C \cap [a,b]$, how do you extend it to be defined on $[a,b]$?

Comment: I’m not sure. However, if you take the Darboux sum of $f$ and replace $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ criteria with $f:C\cap[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ it’s the same as the sum of $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Where $f=F$ for $x\in C$

Comment: @Arbuja This is not true for any extension $F$ you choose. For example, suppose I have $f : \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = x$, and I set $F:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be $F(x) = f(x)$ when $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $F(x) = 0$ otherwise. Then the Darboux sum of $F$ on $[0,1]$ is certainly not the same as the Darboux sum of $f$ on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$.

Comment: Perhaps you believe that if $f$ is continuous on $C \cap [a,b]$, there is a unique Darboux integrable function $F : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x) = f(x)$ on $C \cap [a,b]$. I don't know whether this is true.

Comment: I confused you. $F=f$ such that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) =F(a)$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$. If not than the Darboux sum of $f$ does not equal $F$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that such a function $F$ will always exist if $f$ is continuous on a countable dense set (e.g., $\mathbb{Q}$). [This is not the case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373592/does-every-continuous-map-from-mathbbq-to-mathbbq-extends-continuously).

Comment: Right. $F=f$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ for $a\in T$ and the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R} \setminus T$ is zero. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: So we are no longer assuming that the dense set is countable? I'm quite confused.

Comment: When $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, $f:C\cap[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, $\mu(C)=0$, $C$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=F(a)$, $a\in A$ and $\mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus A)=0$, we get $\int F=\int f$

Comment: Again, you will need to show that such an $A$ and $F$ exist.

Comment: Above, you said "taking the integral of $f$ is like taking the integral on the extension of its domain to all real numbers". You amended this to say it is like taking the integral of $F$ over $A$, where $F$ has the properties you described. But you have not *proven* that such an *F* always exists.

Comment: Take the Darboux sum of $f(x)=x$ for $x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$. Set $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and dense in $\mathbb{R}$ meaning it can approximate arbitrarily close to any real number, so $\lim\limits_{x\to p}f(x)=f(p)$ where $p\in[a,b]$. Variable $p$ can be seen as an input and $f(p)$ is the same as $f(x)=x$ for $x\in[a,b]$. Hence if we partition $[a,b]$ into $\cup_{i=1}^{n}[x_i,x_{i+1}]$, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lim_{x\to p}\inf\limits_{x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[x_i,x_{i+1}]}x(x_{i+1}-x_{i})=\sum\limits\inf\limits_{p\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}p(x_{i+1}-x_{i})<\int f(p)<$

Comment: ...........$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lim_{x\to p}\inf\limits_{x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[x_i,x_{i+1}]}x(x_{i+1}-x_{i})=\sum\limits\inf\limits_{p\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}p(x_{i+1}-x_{i})$ Hence $\int f(x)=\int f(p)$

Comment: Actually $p\notin[a,b]$. $p\in A\cap[a,b]$. As we showed earlier the Darbox sum of $f(x)$ is the Darboux sum of $f(p)$. According to the Lebesgue criteria of Riemann integration, if the discontinuities of $f(p)$, outside the domain or at $\mathbb{R}\setminus p$, has a Lebesgue measure of zero, an integral is defined.

Comment: I understand that you're showing me how the example $f(x)=x$ works out, but this does not mean it holds for general $x$.

Comment: See the whole proof. Replace $f(x)=x$ with a general $f(x)$ and $f(p)=p$ with a general $f(p)$. The proof should work. As long as $\mathbb{R}\setminus p$ has a Lebesgue measure of zero, the area of $f(p)$ exists and is the area of $f(x)$.

Comment: What does $\mathbb{R} \backslash p$ mean? You seem to be using $p$ for the variable of your function.

Comment: $p\in A\cap[a,b]$ such that $\lim\limits_{x\to p}f(x)=f(p)$. If the set of discontinuities of $f(p)$ or $[a,b]\setminus A$ has a Lebesgue measure of zero, the Darboux integral of $f(p)$ exists and is the same as the Darboux integral of $f(x)$. (Remember $x\in{C}$ and $C$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ with a Lebesgue measure of $0$ and check the proof above)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question

Comment: Correction, $\mathbb{R}\setminus{p}$ should have been $[a,b]\setminus A$ where $p\in A\cap[a,b]$. This is the set of discontinuities of $f(p)$

Comment: Your proof is not clear about distinguishing between your functions being restricted to different domains. From what I understand, you write "$f(x)$" to denote the original function $f : C \cap [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, and you write "$f(p)$" to denote a new function $F : [a,b] \backslash A \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x) = f(x)$ for every $x \in C \cap [a,b]$. Is this correct?

Comment: $f(x)$ is $f:C\cap[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ but $f(p)$ is $F:A\cap[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. I made this correction in the third comment of my proof. By the Lebesgue criteria for Riemann Integration if $[a,b]\setminus A$ (which is the set of discontinuities of $F$ ) has a Lebesgue measure of zero, a Reimman Integral exists. As the proof shows, if $F$ has a Riemann Integral so does $f(x)$.

Comment: And what if $[a,b] \backslash A$ doesn't have a lebesgue measure of zero?

Comment: Then the Riemann integral of $F$, and hence $f(x)$, doesn’t exist.